# How to run ansible task based vaule count condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to create one task based on the number of elements in a key.

my input will like below as json input

"srcaddr": "IP_192.168.10.10, IP_192.168.10.12"

or in array of json

"srcaddr": ['IP_192.168.10.10', 'IP_192.168.10.12']

```
  - name: ADD IPv4 IP ADDRESS GROUP
    chkr_fwobj_address:
      ipv4: "group"
      group_name: "ansibleIPv4Group1"
      group_members: "{{ srcaddr }}"
      adom: "{{ adom }}"
    when: "{{ srcaddr |length > 1}}"
```

I want to execute the above task when the count of the element is more than one, of it is more that one the task will create a group and add the members in to the group. if we have only one element then group creation task will be ignored

Comment: What have you actually tried to make it work?

Comment: and if the above code is not working what is the error. you might want to go througg the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. At last welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*when* condition should not be expanded. Correct syntax is

```
when: srcaddr|length > 1
```

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    srcaddr1: ['IP_192.168.10.10']
    srcaddr2: ['IP_192.168.10.10', 'IP_192.168.10.12']
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: There is more then 1 address in the list srcaddr1.
      when: srcaddr1|length > 1
    - debug:
        msg: There is more then 1 address in the list srcaddr2.
      when: srcaddr2|length > 1
```

gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "There is more than 1 address in the list srcaddr2."
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Note: The length of `srcaddr: 'IP_192.168.10.10'` is the length of the **string**. The length of `srcaddr: [ 'IP_192.168.10.10' ]` is the length of the **list**.

Comment: Thanks for the update and i changed "srcaddr": "IP_192.168.10.10" single value, still the above task is running  based on this condition if we have only one element then task should be ignored